# Vimeo on Facebook share/

Tags: facebook, share, vimeo

im trying to display the player from Vimeo on the facebook wall (after clicking the link share).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
<meta name="title" content="Some title" />
<meta name="description" content="Some description" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/xxx/xxx/xx.jpg" />
<link rel="video_src" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXX" />
<meta name="video_height" content="360" />
<meta name="video_width" content="640" />
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta name="medium" content="video" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

using this, facebook doesn't load the video directly. Im not sure why its not working, so anyone with experience - can you tell me where i fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the new Facebook [open graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta tags. I grabbed the vimeo link by going to a vimeo video, clicking embed, clicked "old embed code", and grabbing the url.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/xxx/xxx/xx.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=xxxxxxxx&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=1&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, really i pass through the "facebook developers page" like a thousand times and never actually noticed the open-graph tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it also helps putting one of the four video types as "og:type": "video.movie", "video.episode", "video.tv_show", or "video.other". The Facebook developers page for video objects in OpenGraph can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/video/

Comment: will this work if I have <meta property="og:type" content="website"/> ?

Comment: it's just that I want for the video to show when people share my website on FB but the website is not just the movie..